# How to display a div on ng-mouseover and hide the same div on ng-mouseleave?

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent

The below code displays the div on mouse over , but does not hide the div on mouse leave..How do I correct the code ?

```
<html ng-app="">
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<center>
    <br>
    <p ng-model="x" ng-mouseover="x='true'" ng-mouseleave="x='false'">HOVER HERE</p>
    <br>
    {{x}}
    <div ng-show="x" style="position: relative;top: 100px;left: 0px;width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: grey;"></div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html ng-app="">
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<center>
    <br>
    <p ng-model="x" ng-mouseover="x=true" ng-mouseleave="x=false">HOVER HERE</p>
    <br>
    {{x}}
    <div ng-show="x" style="position: relative;top: 100px;left: 0px;width: 100px;height: 100px;background-color: grey;"></div>

</center>
```

The only change I've made is `x='true'` to `x=true`. (Removed single quotes).
When quotes were there, `x` was getting set to a string. So when evaluating `ng-show='x'`, the `x` was always a string and that always evaluates to a truthy value.